# Join on time part is failing

Tags: teradata

I am facing an issue where i am not able to join two time columns:

The reported date is timestamp 0 with values like 
4/1/2017 19:58:00
8/19/2017 19:58:00

```
Fault_Order_Submitted_Dt DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
Fault_Order_Submitted_Tm INTEGER FORMAT '99:99:99',

sel a.completion_date, b.Fault_Order_Completed_Dt||b.fault_order_submitted_tm as Fault_time from 
DG.LL_FMFTMX  a
inner join DG.fault_order b
on a.fault_number=b.Fault_Order_Num
and cast(a.reported_date as date) =b.fault_order_submitted_dt
and cast(cast( a.reported_date as time(0) ) as integer format '99:99:99') = b.fault_order_submitted_tm
where fault_status='P'
```

The Join part on time is failing with invalid operation on date/time.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

To get the time portion as HHMISS integer you need to cast it to a string first:

```
Cast(To_Char(reported_date, 'hhmiss') AS INT)
```

Comment: Thanks Dieter!! Got it.